# QGIS GRASS decoding error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, encoding, unicodedecodeerror

As many others, as I found out, I to have a problem with GRASS possibly due to location (Czech Republic, Middle Europe).

This is what I get:

```
QGIS version: 3.20.3-Odense
QGIS code revision: 495fbaec
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.3.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 8.1.1, September 1st, 2021
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: eac774)
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.net' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-c' : False, '-s' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'arc_type' : [0,1], 'file' : '', 'input' : 'D:\\___PRÁCE\\_Trebic\\___SUMP\\QGIS\\QGIS - OBECNÝ\\Infrastruktura\\GRASS TEST\\highway OSM - GRASS test.shp|layername=highway OSM - GRASS test', 'operation' : 0, 'output' : 'D:/___PRÁCE/_Trebic/___SUMP/QGIS/QGIS - OBECNÝ/Infrastruktura/GRASS TEST/highway OSM - GRASS test - v.net output.shp', 'points' : None, 'threshold' : 50 }

g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/roman/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_swMmoY/f330db34f2304009a2f4a755c02788d0/crs.prj"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="D:\___PRÁCE\_Trebic\___SUMP\QGIS\QGIS - OBECNÝ\Infrastruktura\GRASS TEST\highway OSM - GRASS test.shp" layer="highway OSM - GRASS test" output="vector_61dbfb697c6332" --overwrite -o
g.region n=49.2778963 s=49.1628118 e=15.9703821 w=15.7839398
v.net input=vector_61dbfb697c6332 operation="nodes" threshold=50 arc_type="line,boundary" output=outputf4fd3c8a74dc4b6d8bd62b60e57a5d27 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="point" input="outputf4fd3c8a74dc4b6d8bd62b60e57a5d27" output="D:/___PRÁCE/_Trebic/___SUMP/QGIS/QGIS - OBECNÝ/Infrastruktura/GRASS TEST/highway OSM - GRASS test - v.net output.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile" layer=2 -c --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
UPOZORNĚNÍ: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_swMmoY\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
D:\___PRµCE\_Trebic\___SUMP\QGIS\QGIS - OBECNí>chcp 1250 1>NUL
D:\___PRÁCE\_Trebic\___SUMP\QGIS\QGIS - OBECNÝ>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/roman/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_swMmoY/f330db34f2304009a2f4a755c02788d0/crs.prj"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 433, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 397, in executeGrass
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 100: character maps to <undefined>

Execution failed after 2.09 seconds

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• D:/___PRÁCE/_Trebic/___SUMP/QGIS/QGIS - OBECNÝ/Infrastruktura/GRASS TEST/highway OSM - GRASS test - v.net output.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

This is what I get most of the times. At times (cannot figure out why), I get no error, but what I generate (from v.net for example) does not make sense (a copy of a point layer that has no place in this, when I check infrastructure).

I understand there is a decoding problem. But I dont get it. I tried changing system language, I tried different projects, different layers, etc. But most often I cannot use GRASS because of this. I actually never could use GRASS in QGIS, which is a shame. I tried this on two different windows 10 computers and 3 different versions (3.14, 3.16, 3.20).

Does anyone have a solution?

EDID: I added the entire LOG message including paths as prompted by another user. I was using v.net on a freshly generated OSM network.

Comment: Can you add what command exactly you are running, and what are the names of the input layers. Please include the **full path** to the inputs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Micha. I have added more information, is that sufficient?

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the paths? For example my GRASS cant handle the swedish åäö characters

Comment: I do, I have Czech characters (Á, Ý, etc.). Is that the problem? Should I move it to a cleaner path?

Comment: We have several Czech core developers in the development team, I'd be surprised to see that not working... is it really GRASS GIS failing? Looks more like a QGIS error in "Processing".

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue, what the problem is. Can I provide some additional information? I would really like to resolve this. But more people have the same error with no apparent solution. Thanks in advance.